# Regular expression for decimals

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Hi Experts,
                   I have a requirement where I think regular expressions might help reducing a lot of if statements and conditions in my code.
My requirement is something like this 
I have a quantity field that is displayed in the UI( JavaScript) which has a control factor (based on the quantity field's Unit of Measurement) send from the backend .

Example my Quantity = "126.768"
The control factor D = "2" (which means the number of display positions after the decimal point is 2) .

Now I need a regex to find the following

Regex1 should check whether the quantity is having any decimal points at all. If so then it should check whether the value after decimal points are not just zeros (ex sometimes quantity comes without getting formatted with the full length of decimal points 145.000, which in our case should be displayed as 145 in the UI and the control factor D doesn't need to be considered). Also RegEx should consider quantity values like ".590" ".001" etc.

Since I am new to RegEx I am struggling to come up with an expression

I managed to make a very basic RegEx that just check for the "." within the quantity and all the values after the "."
RegEx = /[.]\d*/g

If RegEx1 returns a positive result . Then Regex2 should now check for the value  D. It should adjust the decimal points based on D. For example if D = 3 and quantity = 345.26 then the output of regex2 should give 345.260 and similarly is D = 1 then quantity should be 345.3 ( donno whether rounding is possible using RegEx, a solution without rounding is also fine).

Regards,
Bince

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to use regexp to manipulate and format numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first regex is

```
"\d*\.\d*[1-9]\d*"
```

It searches for at least 1 non-zero digit after the dot.

For the second point, you can round with regex only if the digits overcomes the control factor, while for the 0-padding you can't use regex:

```js
function round(num, control) {
  var intPart = num.split(".")[0];
  var decPart = num.split(".")[1];
  decPart = decPart.substring(0, control);  //this does the truncation
  var padding = "0".repeat(control - decPart.length); //this does the 0-padding
  return intPart + "." + decPart + padding;
}

var num1 = "210.012";
var num2 = "210.1";
var control = 2;
console.log(round(num1, control));
console.log(round(num2, control));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :) , I am displaying these quantity as string which is a read only field in the UI. So your solution will suit my scenario.

Comment: you are re-implementing a standard and well-tested native method. This implementation doesn't round to the nearest decimal:  `round('123.256', 2); // expected("123.26") but got("123.25")`. I suggest you this: `function round(num, decimals) { return Number(num).toFixed(decimals) }`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need for any check or regex, 
there is a [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method that will help you to adjust decimals.

It basically rounds a `number` to the nearest `decimal point` and returns a string. If you're working with strings, make sure you cast it before (using `Number` statically)

```js
console.log(17.1234.toFixed(2)); // round it down
console.log(17.1264.toFixed(2)); // round it up
console.log(17..toFixed(2)); // Integer
console.log(Number("126.768").toFixed(2)); // from string casting
```

Comment: I think the OP is having to do with strings, not numbers, otherwise he wouldn't have asked for regular expressions.

Comment: `Number("126.768").toFixed(2)` this should help to work with strings...

Comment: @horcrux but the strings he is dealing with represent numbers.